# Exception inside vectored exception handler

Tags: windows, exception

How to handle exceptions within a vectored exception handler?

If I understand correctly, any excepiton inside such a handler would call the handler function again, despite any SEH or c++ handler in the function -- eventually causing stack overflow. Is there a way to prevent this, without unregistering the handler?

Comment: Set a global flag when your handler starts executing.  Test that flag on entry.  Call TerminateProcess() when it is set, there's no hope of recovering from such a mishap.

Comment: @Hans Passant the process gets terminated anyway, but that's not what I want. Why no hope? I just want to suppress/ignore [some] exceptions inside the handler.

Comment: When your exception filter itself dies on with an exception then, no, there's no hope of recovering.  It *must* be stable.  Fix your code.

Comment: @Hans Passant ok, I see. By the way, unregistering the handler in the handler itself doesn't seem to work!